# Do I need server for app purchase for iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I am one man developer and my apps is pretty simple. The user will purchase and download it in app store. I don't have like lite version or whatsoever. so it is pretty simple. Do I really need server for In-app purchase? I do have free apps in app store. I thought it works like similar. but apparently it is not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between purchasing an app from the app store, and making an in-app purchase AFTER the app has been installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is simply downloaded from the app store you don't need in app purchases at all. In app purchases are for when the user makes a purchase after the app is installed. And you don't need a server to do this either.

Comment: I am kinda confused now after read so many thread. For my app, the user will purchase first before download it. So not like some games lite, you can play and purchase it for more level.

Comment: When you submit your game to apple simply choose a price and you're done. You may have to fill out some tax information before it lets you do this.

Comment: If that's the case then I am done. I have upload the binary already.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily. See the [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1) for specific situations in which you need a server.

If you decide you do need a server but don't want to have your own, take a look at [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) for a good 3rd-party service.

Comment: Yes, my apps should be like in figure 1-1 basic store model. I have attached storekit.framework. Do I need to write extra coding? I do not need to track or anything.

Comment: Look at Figure 1-2, it has an overview of what you need to do.

Comment: lol After I read the introduction. I do not need store kit at all. All I need is to submit and put the price and I am done.
Thanks